# Access string between two characters

Tags: ms-access

Hia,

I have a string ( a URL) where I want to get first string in between two characters in an access query.

http://websiteurl.com/sometext-STUFFIWANT-foo-bar

All the text is variable, and there are a varying number of "-" in the URL.

I can get the position of the first occurrence:

```
Instr([column],"-")+1
```

and I think I want something like:

```
Mid(
    [column],
    Instr([column],"-")+1,
    InStr(InStr(1,[column],"-")-1,[column],"-")
)
```

This is giving me however the first chunk of the string, followed by some of the text after what I want.

I ideally would like:
"get position of first -, the position of the second -, and then return all the text between those 2 positions"

I'm going round in circles a bit, and though I think I'm close, I'm no longer making progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention the context where you're doing this ... a VBA procedure, a query in Access, a query from outside an Access session.  But this could be very easy if you can use the `Split()` function.  Consider this example from the Immediate window.

```vb
strUrl = "http://websiteurl.com/sometext-STUFFIWANT-foo-bar"
varPieces = Split(strUrl, "-")
? varPieces(1)
STUFFIWANT
```

Now that you've said you want to do this in a query, I think you're looking for something like this ...

```vb
SELECT
    Mid(
        [column],
        InStr([column], "-") +1,
        (InStr(InStr([column], "-") +1, [column], "-") - InStr([column], "-")) -1
        ) AS stuff_i_want
FROM YourTable;
```

That might even be sufficient.  However, it will throw "invalid use of Null" errors whenever `[column]` is Null.  And it will also choke on `[column]` values which include less than 2 dashes.  If you can deal with those limitations, you may be good to go.  But if you need to modify that complex field expression ... good luck!

If this is a query you will be running from within an Access application session, you could create a user-defined function based on the `Split()` example I showed you earlier.  Then your query would be simple to write.

```vb
SELECT
    GetStuffYouWant([column]) AS stuff_i_want
FROM YourTable;
```

You may have heard warnings that UDFs can be slow in queries.  However, in this case, the alternative is `Mid()` plus a bunch of `InStr()` functions, and that's not really an easier workload for the db engine.  I compared both approaches with a table which contains over 10 million rows.  The time it took to fully populate a DAO recordset ranged between 37 and 45 seconds, with neither approach as the consistent winner.

If you want to try the UDF approach yourself, I included the function below.  And here is an Immediate window session testing the function with various input values.

```vb
? GetStuffYouWant(Null)
Null
? GetStuffYouWant("")
Null
? GetStuffYouWant("abc")
Null
? GetStuffYouWant("abc-")
Null
? GetStuffYouWant("abc-def")
Null
? GetStuffYouWant("abc-def-")
def
? GetStuffYouWant("http://websiteurl.com/sometext-STUFFIWANT-foo-bar")
STUFFIWANT
```

And the function ...

```vb
Public Function GetStuffYouWant(ByVal pInput As Variant, _
        Optional pSplitChar As String = "-") As Variant
    Dim varResult As Variant
    Dim varPieces As Variant

    If IsNull(pInput) Then
        varResult = Null
    Else
        varPieces = Split(pInput, pSplitChar)
        If UBound(varPieces) > 1 Then
            varResult = varPieces(1)
        Else
            varResult = Null
        End If
    End If
    GetStuffYouWant = varResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really close. Is this what you want to do?

```
   dim first as integer
  dim second as integer
   dim result as string
   first = instr(1,"yourtext","-")
    second = instr(first+1,"yourtext","-")

   if first > 0 and second > first then
           second = second - first
            result = mid("yourtext",first+1, second-1)
     end if
```

for "xx-bbb-cc" , result will be "bbb"

for "xx-bbb-cc-zz-cc, result will be "bbb"

for xxxx-bbb, there will be no result

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem, here is a function you can use, which allows for strings as startbit and endbit delimiters, and finds the middlebit from within the teststring even if the second delimiter isn't found.

```
Public Function middlebit(startbit, endbit, teststring)
Dim first As Integer
Dim second As Integer
middlebit = ""
If teststring <> "" Then
    first = InStr(1, teststring, startbit)
    second = InStr(first + Len(startbit), teststring, endbit)
    If second = 0 Then second = Len(teststring)
    If first > 0 And second > first Then
        second = second - first
        middlebit = Mid(teststring, first + Len(startbit), second - Len(startbit))
    End If
End If
```

End Function